# Only Load Javascript if Supported

Tags: javascript

I don't want my users having to load a ton of JS files if their browser doesn't support it.  What's the best/easiest/fastest to **only** load JS scripts if the browser supports Javascript?

Thanks in advance,
- JS noob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If JavaScript is off, the browser won't download files from the `src` attribute of `<script type='text/javascript'>` tags.

Comment: <Smacks forehead>.  Duh.  Thanks.

Comment: HTH :) [at least 15 characters of padding]